# Netbeans phpdoc/comment formatting

Tags: netbeans

where i can change this stupid formatting, i look at all options in Editor/Format but didn't find anything useful!
When i just wrote comment block:
[image]

and when i press SHIFT+ALT+F or Source/Format in menu comment block is crashed, and all beauty of phpDoc comment is destroyed :(

[image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing what code colouring theme you are using in NetBeans?

Comment: yeah) this is Sunburst theme maybe with some modifications by me, take the link http://zacharywood.com/junk/sunburst_netbeans.zip ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are trying to put a phpDoc block in the middle of code, I believe that NetBeans is giving you some combination of *Initial Indentation* and *Continuation Indentation* (found in Tools|Options|Editor|Formatting where Language = PHP and Category = Tabs and Indents).

The real problem is that docblock comments are not found within the flow of the code. Have a look at the phpDocumentor manual page on [documentable elements](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_elements.pkg.html).  Docblock comments need to go in very specific places, e.g., before functions, before class definitions, before define statements, etc.

In your case, assuming that the try-catch block is within a function, then the @todo would go in the docblock that appears just before the function.

Alternatively, you could switch to the "one-line" comment style, e.g.

```
// @todo - Fix something with the next line
```

but that would not get picked up in phpDoc. (In fact, in your example with the docblock in the flow of the code, I'm not so sure that phpDocumentor would pick that up either.) In addition, it would be indented at least one level in from the try statement, since it appears within the block.