# Adobe Dreamweaver Code Coloring for Laravel Blade

Tags: php, adobe, laravel, dreamweaver, laravel-blade

I guess many people who use Dreamweaver as text editor for Laravel Blade will face the problem of unsupported code / syntax coloring. Without code coloring, the coding is hard to read. Therefore, I decided to do some "hacking" on dreamweaver to get the code coloring works with Laravel Blade.

To do that, you need to go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS6\configuration\CodeColoring folder. Then, edit the php.xml file.

Add the following under the CodeColor_PHPScriptBlock

```
<blockStart doctypes="PHP_MySQL" scheme="customText"><![CDATA[{{]]></blockStart>
<blockEnd><![CDATA[}}]]></blockEnd>
<blockStart doctypes="PHP_MySQL" scheme="customText"><![CDATA[{{{]]></blockStart>
<blockEnd><![CDATA[}}}]]></blockEnd>
```

Then, add the following under the CodeColor_PHPScriptComment

```
<commentStart><![CDATA[--]]></commentStart>
<commentEnd><![CDATA[--]]></commentEnd>
```

Now, you should have the code coloring and the code hinting working.

However, I am still unable to get the Blade syntax coloring works in Dreamweaver. Here are the syntax that are still not working:

```
@section
@show
@yield
@extends
@parent
@stop
@if
@elseif
@else
@endif
@unless
@endunless
@for
@endfor
@foreach
@endforeach
@while
@endwhile
@include
@overwrite
@lang
@choice
```

If you know how to get the above syntax coloring works in Dreamweaver, please share with me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm in favour of programmers using whatever editor they like. That said, DW is generally avoided by programmers, since it's just a GUI editor with a simple text editor bolted on. I'd recommend switching to an IDE such as NetBeans, Eclipse or PHPStorm.

Comment: Which of your mentioned IDE support Laravel Blade in code coloring and hinting?

Comment: I've no idea, I don't use Laravel. Are they docblock-style comments? If so, NetBeans will embolden them ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4297629/472495)) but I'm not sure they can be individually recoloured in NB. Try searching for "<editor> docblock colouring" to see if you can find anything. Or, there may be an NB plugin.

Comment: you can use sublimetext2 as there is a package for that, see dayle rees' post http://daylerees.com/notable-blade-syntax-highlighting-by-medialink

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use @ as blockStart and ) as blockEnd. Problem is to keep track of opening and closing parenthesis.

This is the basic concept here, at github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade (laravel-blade.tmLanguage):

```
<key>foldingStartMarker</key>
<string>\@\b(section)\b(?=(|\s*|)\()</string>
<key>foldingStopMarker</key>
<string>\)(?!.*\))</string>
```